# Resizing CAImageRef in background thread leads to 100% CPU and crashes

Tags: cocoa, thread-safety, core-graphics

From what I read, Core Graphics is supposed to be thread safe. However, when I run the code below in a background thread (via NSOperationQueue) the CPU of my Cocoa app spikes to almost 100% and the program becomes unresponsive.

If I run the same code from the main thread, it works fine.

```
- (CGImageRef) createResizedImageFrom:(CGImageRef)image withSize:(CGSize) size {

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image);
    if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(colorspace) == kCGColorSpaceModelIndexed) {
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
        NSLog(@"Indexed color space not supported.");
        return nil;
    }
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height,
                                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image),
                                                 CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                                 colorspace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

    if(context == NULL)
        return nil;

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), image);
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return imgRef;
}
```

I paused the process from the debugger, but I couldn't find anything in the thread stack traces. I don't know what is causing the CPU to spike. Is there anything I need to do in addition to make the above code thread safe?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was this line:

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```

Color space was obtained via a `get` call, hence is must not be released by the caller. Lesson learned: always double-check source code you get from the web, no matter how trustworthy the site...